# Matching data frame text with dictionary: speeding up the process

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to compare the list in a cell of a pandas DataFrame with tags from a dictionary `mesh` and yield the hits in a list in another column.
As an example, the dict looks like this:

```
{ "mesh-tag 1": (
      [list of UIs],
      [list of treenumbers]
   ),
  "mesh-tag 2": (
      [list of UIs ],   
      [list of treenumbers]
   ), ...}
```

My aim is to compare the abstract text `AbsText` with the mesh-tags in the dictionary and yielding the hitlist per abstract in another column. Therefore I am using nested loops:

```
for i in abstractdf.index:
    # line for line
    meshlist = []
    UIlist = []
    for meshterm in mesh.keys():
        # tag for tag
        if meshterm in abstractdf["AbsText"][i]:
            meshlist.append(meshterm)
            UIlist.append(mesh[meshterm][0])

        abstractdf.set_value(i, "MeSH-Term", meshlist)
        abstractdf.set_value(i, "Descriptor-UI", UIlist)
```

This is actually working, but takes forever for an even small testing data frame. As I am quite new in coding I know this might be circumstantial... :(

Is there any possibility, e.g. using the `np.where` function or sth else to speed the process up?

Any help or suggestions would be great!